# How to delete multiple rows with 2 columns as composite primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, composite-primary-key, multiple-records

My innodb table has the following structure: 4 columns `(CountryID, Year, %Change, Source)`, with the 2 columns `(CountryID, Year)` as the primary key. How do I delete multiple rows other than using a for-loop to delete each row?

I'm looking for something similar to

```
DELETE FROM CPI 
 WHERE CountryID AND Year IN (('AD', 2010), ('AF', 2009), ('AG', 1992))
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?  What isn't working?  It looks like it should work to me.  Do you have dependent tables?

Comment: hi carl. hmm.. i just clarified my question after seeing your comment. hopefully the edit better explains it.

Comment: woops, found it. edited the question to reflect the answer. thanks everyone!

Comment: Yes, definitely helped me, thank you very much! BTW if someone is getting this error **#1241 - Operand should contain 2 column(s)** for me it was caused by putting the **brackets in the wrong place** like this: `DELETE FROM CPI 
 WHERE ((CountryID, Year) IN ('AD', 2010), ('AF', 2009), ('AG', 1992))`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The answer in Oracle is:

```
delete from cpi
 where (countryid, year) in (('AD', 2010), ('AF', 2009), ('AG', 1992))
```

It's fairly standard SQL syntax and I think MySQL is the same.

Comment: thanks! tried in MySQL too and it works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks ,tried with mysql...this is what i was looking for. Works for me.

Comment: tried and tested also works where param filters are returned by sub-query..very helpful...+1 for this

Comment: What is the performance of this approach? 
In your example, all columns involved are part of the composite primary key. I am wondering how this query gonna perform if columns involved do not represent a composite primary key. Say I have a primary key that consists of 4 columns, but I specify only 2 columns of such PK.
How long can this query be? If you have hundreds of records to be removed, this query will be extremely long... any issues with that?

Comment: Hundreds of records is okay @IhorM. This'll work on billions. If you specify the first two columns of the PK then that also won't make much of a difference.