# How to bulk delete in Supabase using multiple columns?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

is the supabase api able to delete multiple rows at a time which are each identified by multiple column values?

something like:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('list_members')
  .delete()
  .in('{list_id,contact_id}', ['{7,2}', '{7,4}']);
```

?

as opposed to a bulk delete using a single column which is [supported](https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/issues/292#issuecomment-1192803878):

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('cities')
  .delete()
  .in('id', ['1', '2'])
```

(aka [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375456/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-with-2-columns-as-composite-primary-key-in-mysql) but for supabase)

### UPDATE

if anyone's curious this is the postgres function i wrote instead, based on much SO guidance.  no guarantee on efficiency but it works.

```
create or replace function bulk_delete_list_members (list_ids bigint [], contact_ids bigint [])
  returns setof bigint
  language PLPGSQL
  as $$
begin
    return query WITH deleted AS (

      delete from list_members
      where (list_id, contact_id) in (
        select list_id, contact_id
        from unnest(list_ids, contact_ids) as x(list_id, contact_id)
      ) returning *

    ) SELECT count(*) FROM deleted;
end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, but another way to do this would be to write a PostgreSQL function and call it using .rpc().

Check out this discussion thread on GitHub: [github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3419](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3419)

Comment: i think you're probably right. yeah that's what i resorted to